# Script creates local admin and then adds it to service with different password

Tags: powershell, service, change-password

I have a script that creates a local user account, sets the password, adds the local account to Administrators group, and then sets a service to run as this account. The problem is when trying to restart the service I get an error:

> Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure.

I found out that when I manually set the password, I'm able to start the service.

The problem seems to be how the password is passed to the `$service.Change($null,...,$password,...,$null)` method.

```
$name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$computer=[ADSI]"WinNT://$name"
$newuser = $computer.Create('User','newuser')
$password = "Password1"
$newuser.SetPassword($password) #this works
$newuser.SetInfo()
$admin = "Administrators"
$group=[ADSI]"WinNT://$name/$admin,Group"
$group.Add($newuser.path)

$service = Get-WmiObject Win32_service -filter "name='ServiceName'"
$service.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,".\newuser",$password,$null,$null,$null) #this doesn't. Password has not changed.
Restart-Service -Name $service.Name
```

```
Restart-Service : Service 'Service Name (ServiceName)' cannot be started due to
the following error: Cannot start service ServiceName on computer '.'.
At C:\Users\superfoo\Documents\Scripts\ServiceUpdate.ps1:68 char:3
+   Restart-Service -Name $serviceControl
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand
```

The `$password` works while creating the account but not for setting the password on the service. I am running the script as administrator.

OS: Windows 10 (x64)
Powershell: Version 5.0.10586.122

Comment: Having some trouble finding the documentation on the .Change() method but it may require a secure-string for the password.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio The method is documented with the class it belongs to ([`Win32_Service`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). It expects the password as a plain string, not a secure string.

Comment: `$service.Change(...)` should produce output. What does it say?

Comment: The ReturnValue is '0' so I thought that meant it was successful.
`__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :`